# Closed form expression for an integral with a cosine function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I am attempting to solve a first-order ODE of the form:

$$y'(x) = {\rm sech}^2(x){\rm sech}'(x) \times(a + b\cos(cx))$$

The part with the constant was easy to solve and I get

$$y(x) = a\int {\rm sech}^2(x){\rm sech}'(x) dx = a\frac{{\rm sech}^3(x)}{3} + C,$$

where $C$ is a constant. However, the part with the cosine term is harder to integrate. I tried simple integration-by-parts since I know the integral of ${\rm sech}^2(x){\rm sech}'(x)$, but I didn't see it leading me anywhere. Wolfram Alpha gave me a hypergeometric function, but I wonder if there is a cleaner closed-form expression for the integral.

Comment: I checked the second part in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int+sech%5E2%28x%29*D%5Bsech%28x%29%2Cx%5D*cos%28c*x%29*dx) and it looks like a nightmare. I don't know how to lead to that neither.